# Opera Next (Chromium?) actions for keybinds

Tags: opera, chromium

As you most likely know, you can't customize short cuts in Opera Next and that creates all kinds of difficulties to users who are trying to migrate from old Opera.

Currently, there is way to customize short cuts via file Preferences in Opera\profile\data\ by adding something like

```
"Basic": 
{
     "ReopenLastClosedTab": [ "Ctrl+Z" ]
}
```

Question is, where can I get list of actions like `ReopenLastClosedTab` from to re-bind other needed things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Opera employee there are next default keybinds:

[Windows](http://pastebin.com/t2MhPFaX)

Linux -> pastebin.com/TvN4Ptkb

Mac -> pastebin.com/3SWGNP7v

Hope this helps other people who are looking to rebind things to their liking.

P.S. For keybinds in Advanced section, you need to enable these keybinds in options (Enable advanced keyboard shortcuts on Browser tab).